# Page Numbers in a PDF are Off; Need Help Changing Them

Tags: pdf, editing, documents, numbering

My problem is one that has been posted here before, a while ago, and the main solution offered was the program "Adobe Acrobat Professional" (which, unfortuantely is too far out of my current software budget); so I though that I would re-check in and see if perhaps there are any more redent PDF editing programs that could solve this problem that would be more affordable than "Acrobat Pro".  Thanks, in advance, for any help or suggestions! Here is a good desscription of the problem:

> I have a digital edition of textbook I bought. The pages are numbered
>   from 1 - 570.  As a result, when I search page 68, it shows page 51 as
>   the first pages originally in the textbook aren't numbered and there's
>   a whole index of some numbered as XVII. What can I do to edit this
>   textbook, or change the page numbers accordingly?

Comment: If a question has been asked before, then it's been asked; please don't duplicate them. If you want newer/better/different answers, earn some reputation and [place a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on the existing question.  Also keep in mind that your budget does not change the relevancy of answers.  There's also multiple answers to the question you're talking about, did you try those?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to edit all the page numbers by hand, you could use the free [PDFXchange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer). It includes a tool to enter and edit textboxes which could cover and replace the existing page numbers. Well, it is probably quite a lengthy task to edit 570+ page numbers and position all of them nicely.

A less elegant but quicker solution would be the [PDF Toolkit](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) ("`pdftk`"). `Pdftk` can excerpt a range of consecutive pages. You thus could assemble a new `pdf` document with pages `17..570||1..16`  This would allow to have proper page navigation. But the first `16` pages would be shifted to the end.